# Zend DB Table Metadata returns null for integer column length

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

Here is the output of what I am getting against my phonenumber column with integer 15 length:

```
 array (size=14)
 'SCHEMA_NAME' => null
 'TABLE_NAME' => string 'companies' (length=9)
 'COLUMN_NAME' => string 'phonenumber' (length=11)
 'COLUMN_POSITION' => int 13
 'DATA_TYPE' => string 'int' (length=3)
 'DEFAULT' => null
 'NULLABLE' => boolean false
 'LENGTH' => null
 'SCALE' => null
 'PRECISION' => null
 'UNSIGNED' => null
 'PRIMARY' => boolean false
 'PRIMARY_POSITION' => null
 'IDENTITY' => boolean false
```

Im using Zend Framework version 1.12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `INT` is a 32 bit signed integer, capable of storing values in a range of -2147483648 through 2147483647.  The maximum possible length is 11.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/integer-types.html

I don't know if Zend does any additional processing based on the length, but from the MySQL perspective, the "length" attribute on numeric columns is a legacy feature from the days of fixed-width terminals, to give the application a hint about the longest possible displayed value.  It does not constrain the actual data stored.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/integer-types.html

Telephone numbers are not really integers, anyway.  They are strings of digits with semantic meaning that is anchored to the left (e.g. country code, city code internationally, NPA/NXX area code/prefix in the US) so the most likely valuable sorting order would be lexical, not numeric, so a `VARCHAR` of appropriate length seems like a more appropriate data type.